# vertically centering an absolute div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3 framework, and the columns they use seem to do a lot of the centering of content for me

using the css

```
.test {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  opacity:0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
```

inside a div with position relative.

works fine in firefox, wondering what needs to be added for it to work the same in safari. I know there are browser specific css to add for cross browser compatibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I fixed it with `webkit` prefix:

```
.test {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  opacity:0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: have to wait since you answered so fast

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of these problems, i suggest you use a javascript library like this:

http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/

You can happily code your css without adding browsers prefixes, prefixfree will do it for you!

Comment: just add it in the functions? it has both css and js prefixes in the extension

Comment: No, you just add the js library to the page (best if you load before all others libraries). Then prefixfree takes care of adding to your css the browser vendor prefixes

Comment: The link (circle in the corner) says download but gets an empty css file

Comment: No, this is the link:

https://raw.github.com/LeaVerou/prefixfree/gh-pages/prefixfree.min.js

it is a javascript library, not a css file.